# UPPAAL Modulo Example

Tags: model-checking

I would like to configure the guard of an edge to be:

```
(turn % 4) == me
```

where turn is a clock variable and me is an int representing a process.

Please give me an example of how to make a guard for the above predicate.

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not fully complete (so I won't mark it as Complete).

However, if you have a "clock x," and want the clock to wrap around from n --> 0, then you add this guard to an edge.

```
if (x == n) ? 0 : x
```